# error running shiny app "can not open connection"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to load the data from .RData file on my computer and I am trying to run a shiny application for that. My code is below, but when I run it I get error "Can not open connection".. Why this error?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    if (inFile == "")
      return(NULL)
    get(inFile$file1, load("E:/RProjects/Dashboard/gender1.RData"))
  })

 output$table <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(dataset()))
      return(NULL)
    head(dataset(), 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(Gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), Height = c(73.847017017515, 
68.7819040458903, 74.1101053917849, 71.7309784033377, 69.8817958611153, 
67.2530156878065, 68.7850812516616, 68.3485155115879, 67.018949662883, 
63.4564939783664), Weight = c(241.893563180437, 162.3104725213, 
212.7408555565, 220.042470303077, 206.349800623871, 152.212155757083, 
183.927888604031, 167.971110489509, 175.92944039571, 156.399676387112
), BMI = c(0.0443566151469252, 0.0343082174614673, 0.0387343292394288, 
0.0427654457094595, 0.0422547891767963, 0.033653156898047, 0.0388739862001733, 
0.0359564180086832, 0.039169072415755, 0.0388404008602306), probability = c(5.77831234737499e-06, 
0.605952546493327, 2.62595199514618e-05, 0.000362873417265588, 
0.00461190097404834, 0.911068673692331, 0.0496119303175197, 0.352335117615303, 
0.139124546478089, 0.343426515632885)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does this work for you on the console? I believe `load` works entirely by side-effect, loading the contents of the `rdata` file into the global environment or some other environment if you specify one. I can't get `get` and `load` to work this way. Where is `inFile` defined? What is your intended action with this?

Comment: if I used InFile for importing csv, it works, but doesn't work with .Rdata  and I referred this site for this code.. `https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vishesh says, I think you might be needing to use `readRDS` instead of `load`, but here's a `shiny` app that allows all three: csv, rds, or rda.

First, quick debugging setup so we have three types of files to test with:

```
write.csv(mtcars, file="mt.csv")
saveRDS(mtcars, file="mt.rds")
save(mtcars, file="mt.rda")
```

(Certainly not needed for a production app.)

Now the app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV, rda, or rds File"),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header (if CSV)", TRUE),
      uiOutput("rda_objname")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  file1_ <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    # might also work with input$file1$type, which is something like
    # 'application/vnd.ms-excel', though for me in testing this was
    # blank for RDS/RDA ...
    a <- input$file1
    a$ext <- tolower(tools::file_ext(input$file1$name))
    # ... though length==1 since we did not do multiple = TRUE
    a$ext <- ifelse(a$ext == "rdata", "rda", a$ext)
    a
  })
  rawdat <- reactive({
    req(file1_())
    inFile <- file1_()
    # if we ever do fileInput(..., multiple = TRUE), this will need to
    # be on a vector of length > 1
    if ("csv" == inFile$ext) {
      return( read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header) )
    } else if ("rds" == inFile$ext) {
      return( readRDS(inFile$datapath) )
    } else if (inFile$ext == "rda") {
      e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
      load(inFile$datapath, envir = e)
      return( e )
    } else return( NULL )    
  })
  output$rda_objname <- renderUI({
    # this only displays a select-input if the input file is valid and
    # an Rdata-looking file, otherwise the select-input is absent
    req(file1_())
    inFile <- file1_()
    if (inFile$ext == "rda") {
      obj <- isolate(ls(envir = rawdat()))
      selectInput("objname", "RDA object name",
                  choices = c("Select object name ...", obj))
    } else return( NULL )
  })
  dat <- reactive({
    req(rawdat())
    inFile <- isolate(file1_())
    if (inFile$ext == "rda") {
      req(input$objname, input$objname %in% ls(envir = rawdat()))
      return( get(input$objname, envir = rawdat()) )
    } else return( rawdat() )
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(dat())
    dat()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you select a CSV or RDS file in the `fileInput`, then it will automatically render the table. If it ends in `.rda` or `.rdata` (case-insensitive), then it will create a selector to choose which object within the rda file (since they really store environments with named objects, not a single object).

Demo: with CSV or RDS:

[image: shiny demo with RDS file]

With an RDA file (that has a single object in it, `mtcars`:

[image: shiny demo with RDA file]

Some other changes from your code:

- instead of using `if (is.null(...))`, I'm using the more `shiny`-esque `req(...)` methodology; it's a little more user-friendly when things don't go as you (the dev) intended;
- I've intentionally `isolate`d a few things that might stand to not be isolated, but I wanted a clear path of reactivity; it is possible if A depends on B and C depends on both A and B that, when A updates, C will update, then B will update, causing C to update again ... dizzying, perhaps, but a consequence of multiple dependency paths.
- Because this accepts both types of storage (one object and multi), I need a two-step to retrieve the data: `rawdat()` might be an environment (RDA) or an actual objecvt; `dat()` will always be an object or `NULL` (if RDA and an object name is not selected).
- I don't need the `else return(NULL)` in `output$rda_objname`, I just have it there for clarity and explicit code in this example; I likely would not have it in my production code.
- I also use `return` a lot here; technically, it is not required in any of these uses, again I'm just being explicit for this example.

Comment: this was really helpful as I was able to curtail other issues as well. Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `readRDS` for reading RData files. Also, you need to specify a `fileInput` UI element which the user can use to browse to the data file.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", label = "Rdata"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    inFile <- input$file
    readRDS(inFile$datapath)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(dataset()))
      return(NULL)
    head(dataset(), 10)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The link you mentioned in the comment explains the usage of `req` which prevents error in your app when the it loads and the user hasn't yet selected the data source.